# Call Admob Ads after X click on multi TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, admob, onclicklistener

i want to Call  my Admob Ads after X click  on multi TextView

this my XML Designe

```
LinerLayout
 ScrollView
  LinerLayout
   TextView
   TextView
   TextView
   TextView
```

and this my little code

```
    // Start Interstitial Ads

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("TEST")
            .build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    // Start After X click

   LinearLayout MyLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Id_Beg);
  // ScrollView MyScroll =(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.Id_Scr);
    MyLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            numberClick++;
            if (numberClick >= 3 && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
              //  mInterstitialAd.show();
               Toast.makeText(begginers.this, "Clicked done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
    // End  After X click
    // End Interstitial Ads
```

Thankies Folks

Comment: Just for Up  :$...